# Angular ng-show multiple conditions (no more than 3 work)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a div which I need to show when any of 5 conditions are true.

**The problem** is that `ng-show` seems to take into consideration only *the first 3 conditions*. I don't know if it's only my problem, cause I couldn't find any related problem.

In the following example I kept moving conditions around, but each time only the first 3 conditions are taken into consideration. Whatever condition falls into the 4th position, does not show the div.

Please let me know if you know a work around in case it's not possible to have more than 3 conditions.

It's a pretty big div, so I post only a part:

```
<div class="row " ng-show="selectedAllP[0] || selectedAllF[0] || selectedAllP || selectedAllD || level">
    <div class="row selectedCase">
        <div><h3 id="choices">Your choices:</h3></div>
        <div class="col-md-4" id="publisher">
            <h4>Publishers</h4>
            <div class="level" ng-hide="selectedAllP[0] || selectedAllP">Select publisher</div>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <tbody id="pub">
                    <tr ng-hide="selectedAllP.Name ===  '   - Any Publisher -'" ng-repeat="roll in selectedAllP" ng-click="deSelectP(roll)">
                        <td class="deselect">{{roll.Name}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-show="selectedAllP.Name ===  '   - Any Publisher -'" ng-click="deSelectP(selectedAllP)">
                        <td class="deselect">{{selectedAllP.Name}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <p ng-show="noticeAnyPublisher && selectedAllP.Name ===  '   - Any Publisher -'" class="notice">{{noticeAnyPublisher}}</p>
        </div>
```

And the logic for a part of the div above:

```
 $scope.selectedAllP = [];

    $scope.setSelectedP = function (publisher) {
        $scope.selectedP = publisher.Name;
        // Check if the selected publisher is already in the array
        // if it isn't, than push it in the array (else do nothing)
        if (publisher.Name == "   - Any Publisher -"){
            $scope.selectedAllP = publisher;
            console.log($scope.selectedAllP);
        } else if ($scope.selectedAllP.Name == "   - Any Publisher -") {
            $scope.noticeAnyPublisher = 'Deselect "Any Publisher" first';
            console.log("blblblb");
        } else if ($scope.selectedAllP.indexOf(publisher) == -1) {
            $scope.selectedAllP.push(publisher);
        }
        console.log($scope.selectedP, $scope.selectedAllP);
    };

    $scope.deSelectP = function (dePublisher) {
        // Check if the selected publisher is already in the array
        // if it is, than remove it from the array (else do nothing)

        if (dePublisher.Name == "   - Any Publisher -") {
            $scope.selectedAllP = [];
            $scope.selectedP = 0;
            $scope.noticeAnyPublisher = '';
        } else {
            var idx = $scope.selectedAllP.indexOf(dePublisher);
            if (idx != -1) {
                $scope.selectedAllP.splice(idx, 1);
                $scope.selectedP = $scope.selectedAllP[0].Name;
            }
        }
    };
```

I want when I choose the 4th condition (in this case || selectedAllD) to show the div above, but as u can see, even if the distributor is selected (and selectedAllD exists in console), the div doesn't show. Check next image to see the div showing when I select the 3rd condition (selectedAllF[0]).

[image]

div showing when I select the 3rd condition (selectedAllF[0]). It is showing for the fisrt 2 conditions too. Problem is that its behavior is the same, whatever the order of the conditions (it only considers the first 3 conditions).

[image]

Comment: Please create a Plunkr to share with us.

Comment: @daan.desmedt Sorry, Iwould, but the code is pretty big, it's from work and I don't know too well how to reformulate it in order to not reveal too much code, but still show exactly how it functions. I was wondering if someone had the same problem or knows better about these conditions from experience.

Comment: @adlisval log the values of the 5 expressions for the two cases you provided above. What are the values of each expression when it works vs when it doesn't work?

Comment: What is indicating to you that there's an issue with the positions of the values, rather than the values themselves? If you have `{{selectedAllP[0] || selectedAllF[0] || selectedAllP || selectedAllD || level}}` and a `{{ }}` expression showing the individual values in the view, what do they show?

Answer (score 3):

You could call a method in your `ng-show`.

`<div class="row " ng-show="showRow()">`

and declare that function into your `.js` file.

```
$scope.showRow = function () {
    return $scope.selectedAllP[0] || $scope.selectedAllF[0] || $scope.selectedAllP || $scope.selectedAllD || $scope.level;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's the same behavior. I reordered the conditions and it's still the first 3 that are considered by ng-show.

Answer (score 2):

No matter how many condition you will pass to `ng-show` or any ohter directive which accepts expressions. See this docs [Angular Expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression). So instead, check all of the parts of you condition statement. In such representation it will be evaluated to true every time when there is AT LEAST 1 statement which returns `true`. Also it is worth to note that this expression will be evaluated from left to right and UNTIL first true statement will be found.

Comment: It seems it was actually a problem with a wrong condition I had. Thanks